# How to add classname and set style for each td of tr table in angular 8

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8, angular12

Trying to add classname and set some style for td of each tr in the table using typescript. I have tried, But it is not working. If anyone knows please help to find the solution.

app.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this.elRef.nativeElement
  .querySelectorAll('#contect table tbody tr')
  .forEach((element, index, array) => {
    console.log(element);

    element.forEach((element, index, array) => {
      if (index == 0) {//first td of tr
        element.classList.add('bg');
        element.style.right = '2px';
      } 
    });
  });
  }
  }
```

Comment: Why don’t you do the style editing in the template? It would be much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

1. Typo: "content" not "contect"
2. Add `element.querySelectorAll('td')`
3. Specify `HTMLElement` as the generic type for `ElementRef` and `querySelectorAll` to get type support.

```js
  constructor(public elRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.elRef.nativeElement
      .querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('#content table tbody tr')
      .forEach((element) => {
        element.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((element, index) => {
          if (index < 2) element.classList.add('bg');
        });
      });
  }
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-svg-use-lw5uhc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: How to apply these css only for the first two column(company and contact?

Comment: If this solved your problem please accept this answer and ask a different question. You can post the link here.

Comment: This is not resolved my issue. Please check my equation. Actually i am trying to apply css for the first two column. So, Please update your stackblitz

Comment: You have any idea?

Comment: @EMahanK `element.forEach(...)` doesn't work because `HTMLTableRowElement` doesn't have the `forEach()` method defined. You can however use `Array.from(element.cells).forEach(...)`. But like already stated in the comments of the question, you're probably better of defining the classes in the template instead.

Comment: @3limin4t0r: Can you edit my stackblitz?

Comment: @EMahanK Fixed TypeScript: https://stackblitz.com/edit/75362846-3982562-01?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts Or the alternative with classes and styles defined in the template https://stackblitz.com/edit/75362846-3982562-02?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @EMahanK edited to only change first two columns